# Edit updating dynamic table content automatically on any change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am facing some problem in an edit modal which loads a row content in a dynamic table. When i click the edit button the modal loads the row content using ngModel and getting data from a function. The problem is when i edit the modal content the table content updates automatically regardless if i hit the save button or not.

My button:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" (click)="passingData(pedido)" data-target="#EditarItem"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>`

My function:

```
passingData (data){
  this._pedido = data;
  this.pedido=this._pedido;
}
```

My modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditarItem" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Requisição</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form name="formRequisicao">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Escolha o produto</label>
             <select id="" class="form-control" name="produto" [(ngModel)]="pedido.nomeProduto">
               <option *ngFor="let pd of produtos" value="{{pd.nome}}">{{pd.nome}}</option>
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Quantidade</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="quantidade" [(ngModel)]="pedido.quantidade" type="number" id="required"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Data</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data" [(ngModel)]="pedido.data">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editarRequisicao()" data-dismiss="modal">Guardar produto</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: because u r using ngModel it is updating the model bidirectional.

Comment: How can i avoid this behavior @sagat?

Comment: Try leaving out the parentheses () like this --> [ngModel]="pedido.nomeProduto on the modal

Comment: Yes! It works @sagat. Thank you! How can i give you your points?

Comment: I will give u a short anwer here

Comment: can u upvote my answer pls

Comment: I accepted your answer @sagat, but I can't upvote it since I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding with `[(ngModel)]` this means you are sending from **source --> target** and from **target --> source**, so called two way data binding. If you leave out these  parentheses () it will behave like an input --> from **source to target**, if u change something you have to handle it separately.

Kind regards